# How to locate master branch?

Tags: git

In the below command:

```
CWD:~/git/VCS $ cat .git/config
 [core]
     repositoryformatversion = 0
     filemode = true
     bare = false
     logallrefupdates = true
 [remote "origin"]
     url = https://github.com/xxxxxx/VCS
     fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 [branch "master"]
     remote = origin
     merge = refs/heads/master
CWD:~/git/VCS $
CWD:~/git/VCS $
CWD:~/git/VCS $ # How to locate refs/heads/master?
```

---

Could not locate master branch, local to the filesystem

How to locate `refs/heads/master` folder path within `../git/VCS`?

Comment: What do you mean by 'locate a branch'?

Comment: @Holloway Physical location of master branch, local to the filesystem

Comment: @Holloway Am assuming `refs/heads/master` is a path where master branch exist in local filesystem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Branches in git don't map to locations on the filesystem. All 'master' is, is a pointer to a commit. If you look in `.git/refs/heads/` you will see a file for each branch in your repository. If you open the `master` file, all you see is a hex string which is the sha of the commit the master branch is pointing to.

When the branch is checked out, the files in the working tree of the repository are the files on the branch.

Comment: `/home/xxxx/git/VCS/.git/refs/heads`  and `/home/xxxx/git/VCS/.git/refs/remotes`Thank you

Comment: @overexchange: be aware that Git will, at times, "pack" references (into a "packed references" file) and *remove* the `.git/refs/heads/<name>` and `.git/refs/remotes/...` files, to save disk space and time. If you want to find the hash ID associated with some reference, use `git rev-parse` to do the job.